# Maximum and minimum average question

Tags: average

During a cricket match, India playing against NZ scored in the following manner:

Partnership | Runs scored

$1$st wicket$~~$ | $112$
$2$nd wicket | $58$
$3$rd wicket$~$ | $72$
$4$th wicket$~$ | $9$
$5$th wicket$~$ | $46$
$6$th wicket$~$ | $23$

**So I suppose there were** $7$ **batsmen who got to bat... right?**

(i) *Find the average runs scored by the first four batsmen*

> (a) $83.5~~~$ (b) $60.5~~~$ (c) $66.8~~~$ (d) Cannot be determined

(ii) *The maximum average runs scored by the first five batsmen could be*

> (a) $80.6~~~$ (b) $66.8~~~$ (c)$76~~~$  (d) Cannot be determined

(iii) *The minimum average runs scored by the last five batsmen could be*

> (a) $53.6~~~$ (b) $44.4~~~$ (c) $66.8~~~$  (d) $0~~~$

(iv) *If the fifth down batsman gets out for a duck, then find the average runs scored by the first six batsmen*

> (a) $67.1~~~$ (b) $63.3~~~$ (c) $48.5~~~$ (d) Cannot be determined

$$~$$
**I'm stuck here...

I don't understand the solutions for the above questions.
Could someone explain with step by step solutions for all the above questions please ?**
  [Here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/cricket/explanation.htm) you can find cricket rules, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partnership_(cricket)) about Partnership...

**Original Answers**

(i) **Original answer**
Ans : (d)
    **Explanation :** You don't know who got out when. Hence, cannot be determined

I don't know how to find out average runs scored by $1$st four batsmen because I don't know which batsman scored how much runs.

(ii) **Original answer**
Ans : (a)
     **Explanation :** Since possibilities are asked about, you will have to consider all possibilities. Assume, the sixth and seventh batsmen have scored zero. Only then will the possibility of the first $5$ batsmen scoring the highest possible average rise.
In this case the maximum possible average for the first $5$ batsmen could be $403/5 = 80.6$

$~~~~~$ *Assume, the sixth and seventh batsmen have scored zero.*

Does this mean there are only seven batsmen?

(iii) **Original answer**
Ans : (d)
**Explanation :** Again it is possible that only the first batsman has scored runs.

Okay ,but how did they get 0 ?

$[403$ (i.e scored by first batsman alone) $+ 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0] /5 = 80.6$ ... Is this the way to calculate the minimum average runs scored by the last five batsmen assuming that only the first batsman has scored runs ? 
But according to the given answer this is wrong... I know this is wrong, but this is what i could think of :(

(iv)**Original answer**
Ans : (d)
 **Explanation :** We cannot find out the number of runs scored by $7$th batsman. Hence the answer is d.

Thanks.

Comment: The batsman's score cannot be determined because there are two batsmen in cricket. Basically this question relies on knowledge of cricket.

Comment: You are assuming that we all know the rules of cricket. While it might be true a large portion of the world's population (India+?), it is most likely not true for "this website's population". Please do form your question in a strictly mathematical manner, or specify the relevant rules of this games (former option being highly preferable).

Comment: @barak manos should I post the rules here instead of giving a link?

Comment: Forming your question in a strictly mathematical manner would be **highly** preferable.

Comment: For (iii) the minimum possible calculation should be $\frac{0+0+0+0+0}{5}$ for the last five batsmen

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer should be $(d)$ because we don't know who went out when. There are a lot of orders possible which makes it difficult to find the runs scored by first four batsmen.

Possible orders may be:-

$x_1+x_2=112$, $x_2+x_3=58$, $x_3+x_4=72$, $x_4+x_5=92$, $x_5+x_6=46$, $x_6+x_7=23$

or,

$x_1+x_2=112$, $x_1+x_3=58$, $x_1+x_4=72$, $x_1+x_5=92$, $x_1+x_6=46$, $x_1+x_7=23$

and a lot more.